# 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. after install bootstrap

Tags: reactjs

I tried to install react-bootstrap using npm and then get this error:

> 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I tried to solve this problem with these methods but it did not work:

- npm install
- npm i react-scripts --save
- remove node_modules and npm i

where is the problem from?
This is a really boring problem

I had this problem before with react-scripts and it was fixed after creating an .env file and adding this code `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to it, But now I got into trouble again after install bootstrap

Edit: package-json file

[image]

Comment: @AjeetShah
yes, I added my package.json

Comment: Probably there was an error while installing the packages. Can you try 1. Delete Node_Modules folder 2. Delete package-lock.json or yarn.lock file 3. do `npm i` or `yarn install`again. Be careful while deletion or keep a backup (maybe git). Because I tried with exact package.json file as your and there was no error. Try with "yarn".